# Cloud9 IDE git setup

Tags: git, gitignore, cloud9-ide

I use Cloud9 as my IDE and want to set up git. 
When I type  $ git config -l
it shows:

```
core.editor=nano
core.whitespace=off
core.excludesfile=~/.gitignore
core.excludesfile=/home/ubuntu/
advice.statusuoption=false
color.ui=true
push.default=simple
```

then I type $ git config --global core.excludesfile
it shows

```
/home/ubuntu/
```

then under my .git folder, I type $ git status. it always shows

```
fatal: cannot use /home/ubuntu/ as an exclude file
```

Could anyone help me solve this question?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove this from your git config:

`core.excludesfile=/home/ubuntu/`

Just edit the file `~/.gitconfig` manually, and remove that line. Directories are not supported for that parameter.

Comment: @tonyhhkung, if this works for you, please accept it as the answer.